# Screen artifacts/pixelation at random on a few different Dell Latitude 3520 notebooks

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude, integrated-graphics, visual-artifacts

We have a few of these Dell Latitude 3520's that have had an odd artifacting issue. The image is not still, it is more like a constantly moving static, and I cannot recreate the issue when I get my hands on them.

I've run lengthy tests of the integrated graphics with no luck, does anyone happen to know what could be causing this?

I have seen it happen upon booting as well as when a user is using the device.

[image: Here is the image I am referring to]

Answer (score 0):

First, test with another Monitor. This divides the problem in two for easier resolution.

This does not appear to be a screen defect. The artifacts are too general across the screen and you have a few of these.

So then, it appears more likely to be drivers or software, or possibly the GPU.

On one machine to test:

1. Run the Dell Driver Update App and update ALL drivers including BIOS (UEFI).
2. Then run the Dell Hardware Diagnostic app and test for hardware (especially the GPU).
3. Update Windows fully.
4. Test at this point for changes.
5. On this one machine, reinstall Windows and do not install any software and test again.This will install necessary drivers.

This is a set up steps that will lead you to a resolution.

Comment: All drivers are up to date, hardware diagnostics have not revealed anything so far, I have been continuously running a GPU/CPU/RAM test, and have not been able to even recreate the issue. I will keep testing it and reply back if I figure out what is causing the issue, as the only solution so far has been just to restart the PC.

Comment: Also (since this is on a few machines) on one of the machines, as I suggested, reinstall Windows to see if that show anything.  Windows install also installs some drivers.